# How to change notificatiion sound within the app (Flutter)

Tags: laravel, firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to do something like whatsapp that can change their notification sound every time receiving the chat, how to do so in flutter code

Answer (score 0):

if you are using local notification package which is here 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

you can easily add custom notification sounds, which you can with simple switch condition based on your user's decision play anything you like.

```
switch(decision):
  case 'x':
     setNotificationSound('assets\x');
     break;
  case 'y':
     setNotificationSound('assets\y');
     break;
```